# Blender 2.8 exports fbx with flipped normals

Tags: modeling

export model from blender 2.8 to UE4-> normals are flipped in ue4. Gotta actually flip the normals in blender for it to come right in ue4. this never happened before.
I use the daily 2.8 build (25.3 as for writing  IDEAS?

Comment: See [Flipped/Inverted Normals Fix (Blender to UE4)](https://youtu.be/1ng6NvhpeO8).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check Face Orientation in the Overlays popover:

[image]

In my opinion, in the 2.80 it's harder to recognize a inverted normals in default shading.

Also check, that your object doesn't have negative scale.

Edit: The negative scale can be a byproduct of mirroring (Crtl M) while in object mode. To combat this, mirror the object while in edit mode, and then flip the normals of the mirrored part. Recalculating Normals works just as well.

Comment: Thanks you so much! I had -X in the scale. should have thought about that. thanks!

Comment: You are the man. I had a problem where an FBX imported into Substance Painter had flipped normals. -x scale in Blender was the culprit. Thank you!